# IF condition with <div> in the view file of MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am able to pass data to view file, but need to display them in different format with . 
I try to use if statement to check the form name. 
It returns error said "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.HtmlString' and 'string'". 
Can I add blocks within IF condition? how to validate data within if condition in view file? Thank you! Here is the code:

```
@{ foreach (var form in @ViewBag.FormContent) 
{
    if (Html.Raw(form.Name) == "xyz") //pull up the title and text for the form   
    {
        @Html.Raw(form.FormTitle)
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; padding:15px;">
                      @Html.Raw(form.FormText)
            </div>
        </div>
     }
}}
```

Comment: It should be like this:                                                                                    @{                                                                                                    foreach (var form in @ViewBag.FormContent) 
{
if (Html.Raw(form.Name) == "xyz") 
{
  <div class="panel-heading"> @Html.Raw(form.FormTitle)</div>
   <div class="panel-body">  @Html.Raw(form.FormText)  </div>          
 }
 } 
}

Comment: You can do it with a string comparison but I would recommend adding an attribute to the view model like a boolean which you can check `@if(isFirstType){.....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTML.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) returns an object that implements IHtmlString.  It does not return a string.  It doesn't even support `ToString`.  Its only member is [ToHtmlString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.tohtmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns a string.

If you want to compare the output of Html.Raw with "xyz", you need to convert it to a string first.  So instead of

```
if (Html.Raw(form.Name) == "xyz")
```

use something like

```
if (Html.Raw(form.Name).ToHtmlString() == "xyz")
```

Or... don't even bother with Html.Raw to begin with.  Don't think you need it.  Just write this:

```
if (form.Name == "xyz")
```

Comment: It works, thank you! the code above is within one <div>. I have another <div> which need to display a pdf or word file on the page. I saved the file in a folder of project, the file's name, and URL in sql table in a column "formURL". How could I call the URL in view? It sounds bad coding if call  @ViewBag.FormContent from two <div> separately.

Comment: To better understand the structure, I have two linkbuttons to call div1 and div2. these two divs are collapsed when loading the page. click the first button will display the div1, which is the code showing above; click the second button will display the word/pdf file. I really can't keep these two divs within foreach. there should be some ways to make this situation work with only process @ViewBag.FormContent once. any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am able to show the .pdf file on browser by using iframe in View file, and filestream in controller. Do you have any idea on calling ViewBag once for showing on/off the two <div>s? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Please post a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't accept direct questions.  If you're having trouble with StackOverflow maybe try getting help on the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: I am able to create new question in details, please check it, thank you so much.